# primefaces dynamic nested datatable

Tags: jsf, checkbox, primefaces, datatable

With primefaces I made a multicheckbox with several divisions to choose. After clicking the submit Button the chosen divisions should be listed in a datatable with the associated items in a subtable. There could be 0 - n items which should be shown in the subtable.

division1 -> item1, item2
division2 -> item3, item4, item5

The first impression of the webpage looks fine. When I only choose one division and press submit the fitting items will be shown. But when I want to display other items they get overwritten. e.g. when I choose division2 it will display the items item1, item2 and item 5.

How can I make it so that the items will be loaded correctly every time?
I also changed the subtable to a nested datatable, but the behaviour was the same.

I've primefaces version 4.0

Below is my code:

division_list.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Gruppenverwaltung</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <f:view>
        <h:form id="myForm">
            <h2>
                <h:outputText value="Division List" />
            </h2>
            <h:outputText value="Grid: " />
            <p:selectOneRadio id="grid" value="#{divisionController.selectedDivisions}" layout="grid" columns="3"
                converter="DivisionConverter">
                <f:selectItems value="#{divisionController.divisions}" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>
            <p:commandButton value="Submit" update=":myForm" />
            <p:dataTable id="dtDivisions" value="#{divisionController.selectedDivisions}" var="division">
                <p:subTable id="stItems" var="item" value="#{division.items}">><f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{division.name}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:column>
                        <h:inputText value="#{item.name}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-disk" action="#{divisionController.doUpdateItem(item)}" />
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" oncomplete="confirm.show()">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{divisionController.selectedItem}" value="#{item}" />
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </p:column>
                </p:subTable>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
        <p:confirmDialog message="Gewählter Eintrag löschen?" widgetVar="confirm"> --><h:form
                id="formDialog">
                <p:commandButton value="Yes" action="#{divisionController.doDeleteItem}"
                    styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" oncomplete="confirmation.hide()" />
                <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" onclick="confirm.hide()" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no"
                    icon="ui-icon-close" />
            </h:form>
        </p:confirmDialog>
    </f:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

DivisonController.java:

```
...
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DivisionController implements Serializable {
...
   private List<DivisionDto>    divisions;

   private List<DivisionDto>    selectedDivisions;
...
   @PostConstruct
   public void init() throws MappingTOException {

   ....
      if (divisions == null) {
         divisions = club.getDivisions();
      }
   }
...
```

DivisionDto.java

```
...
public class DivisionDto {

   ....
   private List<ItemDto> items;
   private String        name;
...
```

ItemDto.java
...
public class ItemDto {
...
   private DivisionDto     division;

private String          name;
...

DivisionConverter.java

```
@FacesConverter(value = "DivisionConverter")
public class DivisionConverter implements Converter {

   private static Map<String, DivisionDto> divisionCache = new HashMap<String, DivisionDto>();

   @Override
   public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {

      DivisionDto val = divisionCache.get(value);
      if (val == null) {
         val = new DivisionDto();
         val.setName(value);
      }
      return val;
   }

   @Override
   public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {

      if (value instanceof DivisionDto) {
         DivisionDto division = (DivisionDto) value;
         divisionCache.put(division.getName(), division);
         return division.getName();
      } else {
         return "";
      }
   }

}
```

I would be really grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue wie a datatable in a datatable and put a filter on the first datatable. Now it works as expected.